# (Redux Form) You must either pass handleSubmit() an onSubmit function or pass onSubmit as a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm a super React-redux beginner and just started working on my first personal project. I'm trying to build submit form using Redex-form and I got the first error I never get over... This is the only place I can have a question.

If you want to see the entire project files, please refer to my github
https://github.com/jlee380/cal-frontend

This is **submit_form.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { submitForm } from '../actions/action_submit_form';
// import { Link } from 'react-router';


class SubmitForms extends Component {
   onSubmit(props) {
     this.props.submitForm(props)
       .then(() => {
          console.log("good submit");
       });
   }

  render() {
    const { fields: { gender, age, height, weight, activity }, 
    handleSubmit } = this.props;

return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.props.submitForm)}>
    <div className="form-group">
      <label className="control-label">Gender</label>
      <select type="gender" className="form-control" id="gender_id" name="gender_name" { ...gender }>
        <option>Male</option>
        <option>Female</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div className="form-group">
      <label className="control-label">Age</label>
      <input type="age" className="form-control" id="age_id" name="age_name" { ...age } />
    </div>
    <div className="form-group">
      <label className="control-label">Height</label>
      <input type="height" className="form-control" id="height_id" name="height_name" { ...height } />
    </div>
    <div className="form-group">
      <label className="control-label">Weight</label>
      <input type="weight" className="form-control" id="weight_id" name="weight_name" { ...weight } />
    </div>
    <div className="form-group">
      <label className="control-label">Activity</label>
      <select type="activity" className="form-control" id="activity_id" name="activity_name" { ...activity }>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div className="form-group">
      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
);
}
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'SubmitNewForm',
  fields: ['gender', 'age', 'height', 'weight', 'activity']
}, null, { submitForm })(SubmitForms);
```

This is action creator **action_submit_form.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const ADD_POST = 'ADD_POST';
const BASE_URL = 'http://138.197.166.14:8000';


export function submitForm(props) {
  console.log('action is hit:');
  const calculatedResult = axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/getcalories`);

  return {
    type: ADD_POST,
    payload: calculatedResult
  };
}
```

This is reducer **index.js**, **reducer_submit_form.js**

```
import reducerSubmitForm from './reducer_submit_form';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';

const rootReducer = combineReducers ({
  post: reducerSubmitForm,
  form: formReducer
});
```

.

```
export default rootReducer;

import { ADD_POST } from '../actions/action_submit_form';

const INITIAL_STATE = { all: [], post: null };

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_POST':
      return{ ...state, all: action.payload.data };
    default:
      return state;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is pretty straightforward.

Check the following line in your SubmitForms Class render method:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.props.submitForm)}>
```

If you log this, what is your output?

```
handleSubmit(this.props.submitForm)
```

According to redux form [documentation](https://redux-form.com/6.6.1/docs/api/form.md/) a submit function must be passed to onSubmit.

Comment: I did console.log(handleSubmit(this.props.submitForm)); console in chrome browser. Is that the right place ?? anyway I got error "VM5884:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: handleSubmit is not defined".

Comment: @JongHunLee That is the issue. You are passing an undefined value to "onSubmit" prop, which should be a function. I don't see any reference in your code to "handleSubmit" so I assume this is the remains of an example you probably copy-pasted and edited?

Comment: Not copy and paste but I referred to udemy course that I learned react from. this is the course projects I referred to [LINK](https://github.com/jlee380/reduxForm)

Answer (score 0):

The `onSubmit` function should be set in the call to `reduxForm`. You `<form>` tag onSubmit handler should be simply a reference to the function `handleSubmit` that Redux Form injects for you. I would agree the naming is a bit chaotic. :)

See the example in the docs:
https://redux-form.com/7.1.2/docs/gettingstarted.md/#step-2-of-4-form-component

```
let ContactForm = props => {
  const { handleSubmit } = props
  return (
    <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit }>
      { /* form body*/ }
    </form>
  )
}
```

Where `ContactForm` is the component that you decorate with `reduxForm` as shown below:

```
ContactForm = reduxForm({
  // a unique name for the form
  form: 'contact',
  // you can define your custom onSubmit here!
  onSubmit: ...
})(ContactForm)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. after taking a look at link that you gave, I will try your solution and tell you the result. Thanks!